# Persistent "held broken packages" error

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install netflix-desktop` gives the error

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 netflix-desktop : Depends: wine-browser-installer but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

but `dpkg --get-selections | grep hold` shows nothing.

I'm running 12.04 64-bit. I've followed the directions in [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies):

1. Confirmed that main, universe, restricted and multiverse software sources are enabled
2. `sudo apt-get clean`
3. `sudo apt-get -f install` (returning '0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.')
4. `sudo dpkg --configure -a`
5. `sudo apt-get -f install` (again '0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.)
6. `sudo apt-get -u dist-upgrade` (0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.)
7. used Y PPA Manager to check for duplicate ppas (none found)

[Edit] I have had the same error with other packages.  Here's the output requested by Alaa:

```
sudo apt-get install wine-browser-installer

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine-browser-installer : Depends: wine-compholio (>= 1.5.19~precise1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

[Edit 2] doing `sudo apt-get install wine-compholio` gave a list of further dependencies.  I installed each one, and now I have done `sudo apt-get install netflix-desktop` without error

Comment: What happens if you `sudo apt-get install wine-browser-installer`?

Comment: Whenever I have installation problems, my first move is `sudo apt-get -f update` followed by `sudo apt-get -f upgrade`. Then try installing your new package.

Comment: When i see "packages held back" i try Marc's comment, or to install the held back packages manualy, or even with apt-get specifying the package name.

Comment: I also see youre using a different version of wine, so why dont you try upgrading the specific version of wine compholio that you have? http://www.compholio.com/wine-compholio/ this version is now in 1.5.3, and may work better if you follow the directions from the package maintainer's site.